# sync Android autocorrect with MS Office?

Tags: android

I rely very heavily upon my  MS Office customized autocorrect settings. I even use it to write complete sentences, by just inputting a code.  Is there a way to sync or export Windows autocorrect to Android?
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Which Android keyboard are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://word.mvps.org/Downloads/AutoCorrect.zip) VBS Macro to extract all your auto correct entries, and then put them in a [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database formatted according to the android keyboard you use.